# ClassCastException:class by.AppInit cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

Help!! All answers what I found: 
change javax.servlet-api version on 3.0.1
change on org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:3.0.20100224
change scope on provided, change spring version on 5.1.6.RELEASE, openJDK 11 not work. 
Start: mvn tomcat7:run
Clean and install project have't errors.

---

[AppInit configure from spring docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(AppInit.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}}
```

WebConf:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("connection.password"));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("connection.driver_class"));
    dataSource.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.max_total")));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean
            = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("by/entity");
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("by/entity");

    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

    return properties;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager();

    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}}
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/booking]]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/booking]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class by.AppInit cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer (by.AppInit is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @139bdc32; javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer is in unnamed module of loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @64a8d575)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

Thank you in advance!